# Intent not using special characters

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent

I created a browser application that take in a URL through an intent call, however in some of the intents I am using the `#` symbol and it is not being processed correctly.

Is it my intent or my application that needs to edited, and how?

My app code:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String url = intent.getStringExtra("id");

if( url == null) {
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
else {
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

My intent:

```
intent://#Intent;action=android.intent.action.SEND;component=myprogramstuff;S.id="https://blahblahblah/#/blah/blah?stuff=123123123";end
```

Comment: What is the content of `intent.getStringExtra("id")`?

Comment: @MuratK. the S.id that is in the intent. In this case: <https://blahblahblah/#/blah/blah?stuff=123123123>?

Comment: Does it normally work in the browser?

Comment: @MuratK. URLs without the # symbol work fine. So if it was just https ://blahblahblah/ It loads with no issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to load the url but you cannot pass the "#" trough intent maybe you can decode your characters into a html readable way. Replace your "#" for "%23" and try.

Comment: This seems to work. Thank you. Would up-vote but reputation too low.

Comment: mark as correct answer? you should be able to do that